# Iterate over an Array and push elements to an Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array object which looks like this

```
identificationType: "DL",
identificationDesc: "Test",
referenceNumber: "123456789",
country: "US",
province: "Illinois"
```

I want my data model to look like this

```
identificationType: "DL",
identificationDesc: "Test",
referenceNumber: "123456789",
issuedEntity:{
country: "US",
province: "Illinois"
}
```

Initially I assign array of Objects to a variable

```
identification: this.model['identificationArray'].
```

IdentificationArray is an array of Object and contains all the details but in a simple json format. I want to be able to somehow manipulate it and insert data by creating an issuedEntity object and then country and province details inside that object.

For that I tried iterating over the array but I am getting error.Can someone help me figure out how to do it.

```
myModel.identification.forEach(identificationObj => {
issuedEntity: {
province = identificationObj.issuedEntity.province,
country = identificationObj.issuedEntity.country,
}
} 
);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array map function and return an object with required keys

```js
let data = [{
  identificationType: "DL",
  identificationDesc: "Test",
  referenceNumber: "123456789",
  country: "US",
  province: "Illinois"
}]

let newData = data.map(function(item) {
  return {
    identificationType: item.identificationType,
    identificationDesc: item.identificationDesc,
    referenceNumber: item.referenceNumber,
    issuedEntity: {
      country: item.country,
      province: item.province
    }

  }
});

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: I was thinking the same!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you might want to use **ES6 Syntax**, you'd do the same thing like this:

```js
let data = [{
  identificationType: "DL",
  identificationDesc: "Test",
  referenceNumber: "123456789",
  country: "US",
  province: "Illinois"
}]

let newData = data.map(({
  identificationType,
  identificationDesc,
  referenceNumber,
  country,
  province
}) => ({
  identificationType,
  identificationDesc,
  referenceNumber,
  issuedEntity: {
    country,
    province
  }
}));

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` over your original object and change it's internal values or addon external values to it.

```
myModel.identification.map(idObj => {
   idObj.issuedEntity = {
       province: idObj.province
       country: idObj.country
   }
   delete idObj.province
   delete idObj.country
   return idObj
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here, we are using `=` instead of `:` colon when assigning value to object.

```
    myModel.identification.forEach(identificationObj => {
    issuedEntity: {
        province **=** identificationObj.issuedEntity.province,
        country **=** identificationObj.issuedEntity.country,
    }
});
```

It should be like this

```
myModel.identification.forEach(identificationObj => {
    issuedEntity: {
        province: identificationObj.issuedEntity.province,
        country: identificationObj.issuedEntity.country,
    }
});
```